# Efficient way to aggregate on groupby dataFrame and output to new DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to see if there is a better and more efficient way of doing this: 

Sample Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'ID' : ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'], 
'Month' : [-4,-3,1,2,-3,-2,1,2],
'Cost' : [20,30,10,15,1,2,5,10] })
```

Then, I groupbyID:

`df = df.groupby(ID)` 
Then, I aggregate the cost with a condition of <0 and >0 in a for loop and save the output to a new dataFrame:

```
output = pd.DataFrame([])
for group, data in df:
    totalPre = 0
    totalPost = 0
    for row_index, row in data.iterrows():
            if row ['Month'] < 0:
                totalPre = totalPre + row ['Cost']
            elif row['Month'] > 0:
                totalPost = totalPost + row ['Cost']
    output = output.append(pd.DataFrame({'ID': group, 'Total pre': totalPre,'Total post': totalPost }, index=[0]), ignore_index=True)
```

And here is the output:

```
index  ID.  Total pre   Total post
0      A       50         25
1      B       3          15
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in several ways.

One way is filtering before `groupby`

```py
df1 = df[df["Month"]<0].groupby("ID")["Cost"].sum()\
                       .reset_index(name="Total_pre")

df2 = df[df["Month"]>0].groupby("ID")["Cost"].sum()\
                       .reset_index(name="Total_post")

out = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="ID", how="outer")
```

Another is grouping by `ID` and condition and then using `pd.pivot_table`

```py
out = df.groupby(["ID", df["Month"]<0])["Cost"].sum()\
        .reset_index()

out = pd.pivot_table(out,
                     index="ID",
                     columns="Month",
                     values="Cost")\
        .reset_index()\
        .rename(columns={"False":"Total_post",
                         "True":"Total_pre"})

out.columns.name = None
```

**EDIT**
In the last case if you need to exclude the case Month is 0 you can add this filter `df["Month"]!=0` before `groupby`

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a good and simple alternative!

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame([])
df_1 = df_1.assign(totalPre=df[df['Month'] < 0].groupby('ID')['Cost'].sum(), 
                   totalPost= df[df['Month'] > 0].groupby('ID')['Cost'].sum())
print(df_1)
```

Output:

```
    totalPre  totalPost
ID
A         50         25
B          3         15
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `mask` with `GroupBy.sum`:

```
grp = df.mask(df['Month']>0).groupby('ID', as_index=False)['Cost'].sum().rename(columns={'Cost':'Total pre'})
grp['Total post'] = df.mask(df['Month']<0).groupby('ID')['Cost'].sum().to_numpy()
```

**Output**

```
  ID  Total pre  Total post
0  A       50.0        25.0
1  B        3.0        15.0
```

---

**Details**

`mask` sets the rows which match the conditions (`Month > 0`) to `NaN`, so this way we can `groupby.sum` and only get the correct rows:

```
df.mask(df['Month']>0)

    ID  Month  Cost
0    A   -4.0  20.0
1    A   -3.0  30.0
2  NaN    NaN   NaN
3  NaN    NaN   NaN
4    B   -3.0   1.0
5    B   -2.0   2.0
6  NaN    NaN   NaN
7  NaN    NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to filter out the `Month==0`<sup>1</sup> and then group by the `ID` and the condition that the month is less than 0.

```
output = df[df["Month"]!=0].groupby(["ID", df["Month"]<0])["Cost"].sum()\
    .unstack().reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
    .rename(columns={True: "Total pre", False: "Total post"})

print(output)
#  ID  Total post  Total pre
#0  A          25         50
#1  B          15          3
```

<sup>1</sup> Since you seem to indicate that your condition should be strictly greater than/less than.

Answer (score 0):

For loops are rarely the only and the best solution in pandas. I would probably create a new column for the pre/post condition and then group by `ID` and the new column. [Group by](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html) creates a DataFrame for every unique combination of values in the columns that you specify and then aggregates the values using a function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame ({'ID' : ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'], 
'Month' : [-4,-3,1,2,-3,-2,1,2],
'Cost' : [20,30,10,15,1,2,5,10] })

# Create a new column `Timepoint` to group by
df['Timepoint'] = (df['Month'] <= 0).replace({True: 'pre', False: 'post'})
# Create a group for each unique combination of `ID` and `Timepoint` and aggregate the `Cost` using the function `sum`.
output = df.groupby(['ID', 'Timepoint'])['Cost'].sum()
```

My output:

```
Timepoint  post  pre
ID                  
A            25   50
B            15    3
```